# How does SSH frame/packet/segment look like (structure)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to understand the in-depth details of ssh tunneling. Tunneling is the process of placing one package inside another one for transimission. So I'd like to see how SSH packages those packets. Maybe it could help me understand how SSH server than unpackages them.

However, I can't find any information about that structure. There's a lot of information for similar technologies, e.g. IPSec datagram structure, but nothing for SSH.

Probably I'm misunderstanding something. Any insight is appreciated!